# openpyxl - "load_workbook" not defined

Tags: python, openpyxl

I am going through the openpyxl documentation and cannot get load_workbook to work

`from openpyxl import` 
`wb = load_workbook(path.xlxs)`

OUTPUT:

`wb = load_workbook('path.xlsx')` 
`NameError: name 'load_workbook' is not defined`

Other openpyxl methods are working fine.
Verson 3.0.1

Have removed and reinstalled using pip.
Thanks,

Answer (score 6):

you have to import `load_workbook` explicitly

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook

wb = load_workbook('path.xlsx')
```

Comment: Thanks, works now.Can I ask why ```import openpyxl``` doesn't work?

Comment: @TheMob this doesn't work because when you just run `import openpyxl`, you have to tag `openpyxl` before using the functions it provides.

For example, this works as well:

`import openpyxl` and on the next line `wb = openpyxl.load_workbook('path.xlsx')`

Answer (score 0):

```
import openpyxl
```

should also work (at least for Python 3), however to use the load_workbook method you need to type:

```
openpyxl.load_workbook(YourFilePath)
```